# Modify and save audio files with afplay

Tags: macos, audio, music

I discovered the command line program `afplay` and it can turn a audio file up / down very quickly and I want this file to be saved afterwards.

I don't know of any program like this that can change details so quickly.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
afplay audio.mp3 -v 2 > new_audio.mp3
```

Comment: And what about music. Unfortunately, it doesn't work there either

Comment: I think it is not possible because afplay cannot recreate a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afplay` *options* are for *playback* of the *audio file* and redirecting as you have in the *command* `afplay audio.mp3 -v 2 > new_audio.mp3` just creates a zero length *file* because the *output* `afplay` goes to the *sound system*, not `stdout` for redirection.

The **Audio File Play** in the **help** *output* kind of says it all.

If you want to modify/create *audio files*, then you'll need to use program designed for that as `afplay` is designed for *playback*.

```
% afplay -h

    Audio File Play
    Version: 2.0
    Copyright 2003-2013, Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Specify -h (-help) for command options

Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
%
```